# How do I used javascript to perform operations on an audio tag?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I would like to use javascript to interact with an `<audio>` tag (http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp) on my web page.

How do I restart audio, pause audio, change the volume, or otherwise interact with the `<audio>` tag using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some useful links,

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-html5-audio-tag-javascript-manipulation/